# FolderBrowseDialog Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have an silverlight 4 application, and I want to upload recursively a local folder on the server.
For upload files separatly, there is OpenFileDialog method, But I can not select a folder path.

Does exist an equivalent of the WPF "FolderBrowseDialog" method in silverlight ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. That functionality is disabled for security reasons.

See [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.openfiledialog%28VS.95%29.aspx) for further information.

From above link:

> Silverlight does not have a browse
>   folder dialog box and you cannot use
>   the OpenFileDialog  to just select a
>   folder.